# Google maps fits bound in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fullscreen, fitbounds

I have a problem with Google Maps in fullscreen : when it needs to fit the  bounds of markers it works in the small div, but in fullscreen it fits like it was in the small div again.

What I need is that it "zooms in to fits bounds" when I go fullscreen, and it "zooms out to fits bounds" when I go back in small div.

Is there anything possible to do ?

Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/cmjcs5eL/

```
function updateBounds() {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You need an event listener for when the window is resized:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', updateBounds);
```

Comment: This centers the maps on the 2 markers, but doesn't zoom in to fit bounds on them.